# Set backgrund with Data-Binding from view

Tags: c#, android, mvvm

I want to use databinding to set background image of a Button. I can bind Text and src images but im missing something with buttons...

**This i what I have now..**

Viewmodel

```cs
public string VariantBoxGradient { get; set; } = 'imageName';
```

View

```cs
_openRouteButton = FindViewById<ButtonOpacity>(Resource.Id.myId);

BindingSet.Bind(_openRouteButton).For(x => x.Background).To(vm => vm.VariantBoxGradient);
```

axml

```
<ButtonOpacity
    android:id="@+id/myId"
    ...
    // android:background="@drawable/imageName" // This i want to remove
/>
```

**This is what already works**

Viewmodel

```cs
public string VariantPic1 { get; set; } = 'step1_image';
public string TextDescriptionPic1 => string.Format('Something');
```

View

```cs
var infoPic1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.info_pic1);
var descriptionPic1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.info_description_pic1);

BindingSet.Bind(infoPic1).For("DrawableName").To(vm => vm.VariantPic1);
BindingSet.Bind(descriptionPic1).For(x => x.Text).To(vm => vm.TextDescriptionPic1);
```

axml

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/info_pic1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/info_description_pic1"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it doing this:

_openRouteButton = FindViewById(Resource.Id.myId);

_openRouteButton.SetBackgroundResource(Resources.GetIdentifier(ViewModel. VariantBoxGradient, "drawable", PackageName));